@PreAuthorize Doesn't Enforce Scope Restrictions in Spring Boot Resource Server with Keycloak
I’m working on a Spring Boot application with a backend configured as a resource server. The authentication and authorization are managed by Keycloak. The issue is that even when users do not have the required scope in their token, they are able to access protected endpoints.
By the way I am following this documentation :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization
What I’m Trying to Achieve
I am trying to secure my endpoints in a Spring Boot application using the @PreAuthorize annotation.
For example:
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_admin')")
@PostMapping("/{id}")
public File updateFile(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody File file) {
    // Endpoint logic
}

When using the following security configuration, everything works as expected:
Security Configuration
Here’s my security configuration:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/files/{id}").access(hasScope("admin")) // Require 'admin' scope for POST
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/files").access(hasScope("admin")) // Allow 'admin' scope for GET
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/files").access(hasScope("user")) // Allow 'user' scope for GET
            .requestMatchers("/api/files/public-endpoint").permitAll() // Public access for specific endpoint
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // All other endpoints require authentication
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->  oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults());
}

    return http.build();
}


Controller Code
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/files")
public class FilesController {

    private final FileService fileService;

    public FilesController(FileService fileService) {
        this.fileService = fileService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/public-endpoint")
    public String publicEndpoint() {
        return "This is a public endpoint!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_admin')") // Requires 'admin' scope
    public File updateFile(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody File file) {
        if (!id.equals(file.getId())) {
            return null;
        }
        Optional<File> toUpdate = this.fileService.findById(id);
        if (toUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.fileService.update(file);
    }

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_user')") // Tried with this too 
    public List<File> findAllFiles() {
        return this.fileService.findAll();
    }
}

Keycloak Token
With my admin user
"scope": "openid profile admin email",

With my others users
"scope": "openid profile email user",

Problem
When I switch to using @PreAuthorize annotations for method-level security, the behavior changes. All users can access the endpoints regardless of the scopes in their tokens.
What could be causing this, and how can I properly configure @PreAuthorize to enforce scope-based access control?
What I’ve Tried

Verified Token contents
Tried boths methods

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_admin')")

I know that it is possible to use a custom JwtAuthenticationConverter to map my own authorities, but I would prefer to use the native approach with scopes
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The /api/files/ is wrong as that should be /api/files/** to match. You did enable annotation processing for @PreAuthorize?

"Thanks! I edited my post before seeing your response because I found the solution myself for the configuration, and it now works. However, I still have an issue with the @PreAuthorize annotation. I am using hasAuthority because the Spring documentation suggests it, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected."

Did you enable annotation processing? If not the annotation doesn't do anything. Also you added a custom process so what does your jwtAuthenticationConverter actually do?

I will look around annotation processing and back here. Apologies for the mention of jwtAuthentication—that was a copy-paste error, and I’m not actually using it.

As a side note, scopes are not roles, this is why Keycloak puts roles in different claims by default. I wrote a Baeldung article to get started with Keycloak & Spring. Also, the starter hosted in the repo of the 1st link makes it easy to use Keycloak default roles claims (it's a bit painful with just the "official" starter to take roles from nested claims).

@ch4mp Yes, I know that. It was just for testing. Now, I am going to associate different scopes with each profile.

Read the content at the first link more carefully. A user "profile" (or group, role, authority, permission, etc.) is an attribute of the user defining his access to resources, independently of the client application he uses to interact with these resources. A "scope" is an attribute of a client application that defines what a user granted this client application to do on its behalf with the resources he can access. You'd better keep Keycloak defaults: scope for scopes and realm_access.roles & resource_access.{client-id}.roles for roles.

Okay, I understand what you mean. I think I had a little confusion regarding the use of scopes in client applications. Keycloak uses scopes for fine-grained authorization, and that’s what I wanted to achieve. For example, I planned to add a policy in Keycloak and then use a scope for it, such as file:read or file:write.
I'll read your tutorial to get more information and reflect on why and how I should use authorities with Keycloak!

Policy enforcement on the authorization server sucks. You'd better use "realm" roles and "client" roles, and implement RBAC in resource servers.

Thanks the issues came from from the annotation processing!
I changed @EnableWebSecurity by @EnableMethodSecurity and now it works!

You shouldn't change it, you should add it. Else it will render the HttpSecurity in yuor config useless.

Ok, thank you. I'll add it then.
